# How replace the default Azure 403 error page

Tags: asp.net, azure, web-config, certificate

I've got an ASP.NET MVC deployed to Azure and users login though the use of client certificate.
Locally, if the user don't send a certificate or it's invalid, the website redirects the user to /error/403 endpoint.
But on Azure this doesn't work: the user is not redirect to /error/403 and the page displayed is always this:
[image]

This is my Web.Config code inside `<system.webServer>` node:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <clear />
  <error statusCode="400" path="/error/400" responseMode="Redirect" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/error/404" responseMode="Redirect" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="/error/500" responseMode="Redirect" />
  <error statusCode="501" path="/error/501" responseMode="Redirect" />
  <error statusCode="503" path="/error/503" responseMode="Redirect" />
</httpErrors>-->
```

I've also tried to add `<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />` or move my code from `system.webServer` to `system.web` using `customErrors` nodes, but it seems that the user is blocked **before** the web.config has been read. The behavior remained the same for every change I've tried.

How can I solve? Thanks

Comment: HTTP status 403 Forbidden means you're not allowed to access the page. You can return it yourself when a logged in user doesn't have permission to view a page, but in this case it's the Azure platform returning the error, not your application.

Comment: And is there a way to edit this setting in Azure? I mean, change the default blue screen with a custom one. Unfortunately I didn't find anything on Azure portal

Comment: @Krusty any news? workarounds?

Comment: No, I stopped to work on that project because I left the company. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not supported feature by Azure as of right now. The feedback from App Service Team is pretty recent in this [post](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/9912714-enable-users-to-create-custom-error-pages-for-403). However, there is a certain way to get around it via this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49526879/is-it-possible-to-perform-configuration-changes-to-an-azure-web-app-without-the/49528370#49528370) talking about deployment slots.

Comment: I am currently studying for the AZ-900 exam (Azure Fundamentals) and it seems the Azure Gateway put in front of the web app (VM or App Service is the same) is able to display a customized error page

Comment: You are on to something. The Azure Gateway could be utilized for that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your website is not running.

There are 3 possible causes for an Azure website to stop:

- It has reached a billing limit and your site has been disabled.
- It has been stopped in the portal.
- It has reached a resource quota limit that applies to either Free or Shared scale modes.

Please check the Azure portal for any of these conditions.

Comment: My website is running. If I select the correct client certificate, I'll be logged into the app correctly. It's just a default page for 403 error and I'm trying to replace it with another custom page

Comment: So you can see it working on Azure? but you only see this error if you don't "select the correct client certificate?" Can you expand on "select the correct client certificate"? I'm not sure what you mean.