# Is it possible to perform configuration changes to an Azure Web App without the application restarting?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Currently when pushing updates via our CI/CD pipeline to the Azure Web Apps the nodes are being forcefully rebooted by azure once the configuration changes are completed.

Has anyone come across a way where you can apply a configuration (web.config or other) changes to the web app in a single slot configuration with out the forced restart?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot. Azure App Services (web apps) run on IIS. When you touch the web.config, IIS automatically restarts the app domain.

Comment: It's a feature :) You should probably look at deployment slots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Fabrizio Accatino said, when you touch the web.config, IIS automatically restarts the app domain.

If you do this to avoid downtime, you could add a **deployment slot** and publish your newest project to it. When you want to publish your project to production environment,you can **swap** them.For more details, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing#add-a-deployment-slot).

Comment: Hi Joy, thanks for the response. In my question I do reference if this can be done in a single slot. I have edited the question to phrase it better

Answer (score 2):

If downtime is your concern, it looks like MS starts up another container when you hit Save in the application settings blade, and then transfers all new requests over to the new container.  The old container is given 2 min to complete all requests, and is then shut down.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f15b207b-c063-46e5-b87a-2b157641c8c4/does-changing-an-app-setting-and-saving-restart-the-app?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

I tested this on a Web App by repeatedly hitting an endpoint for 30 seconds while I changed an application setting and hit save.  I saw the application start, but did not see any timeouts, only 200 OKs.
FYI my web app only used a single slot.