# How to set a custom error page for azure application gateway 403 page

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I want to display custom error page when app service is down.

I am using error page setting in app gateway's Listener. Setting a public html file path in both 502 and 403 errors. Still gateway is returning same default error page.

Is this error setting support stopped?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a custom Azure 403 page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50166342/how-to-set-a-custom-azure-403-page)

Comment: No, I tried the solution still not working. What I am missing here? Is public blob html is mandatory? Not possible if I provide a static website url?

Answer (score 1):

Application Gateway allows you to create custom error pages instead of displaying default error pages. Custom error pages are supported for the following two scenarios:

1. Maintenance page - This custom error page is sent instead of a 502
   bad gateway page.
2. Unauthorized access page - This custom error page
   is sent instead of a 403 unauthorized access page.

To create a custom error page, you must have:

- an HTTP response status code.
- the corresponding location for the error page.
- a publicly accessible Azure storage blob for the location.
- an *.htm or *.html extension type.

So, you must specify a publicly accessible blob URL for the given error status code.

Reference :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-listeners#custom-error-pages
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/custom-error

Comment: Public blob is not allowed in my organization. Is there any alternate? I tried with different custom page url, it is not working. Anything possible by rewrite url in gateway? If status code is 403, I want to change status code to 301 and set "Location" header to error page url.

Comment: I have reached out to the backend team regarding this. Will update as soon as I hear from them.

Comment: Below is the update from the backend team:
There is no other alternative to Blob storage. The rewrite URL option won’t work because although it can be used to set the Location header based on the “http_status” server variable condition, the response cannot be changed to 301.

Comment: When serving a maintenance page, can you make appgateway server a status code of 200 rather than 502?