# Customize azure 403 Forbidden error page for ASP.Net web app

Tags: asp.net, azure, error-handling, azure-web-app-service

Please do help me to customize azure 403 forbidden error page for Asp.Net. below is the picture what I am getting, if I return 403 forbidden.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a custom Azure 403 page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50166342/how-to-set-a-custom-azure-403-page)

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible workaround:
You can route all traffic to your WebApp via your own load balancer or **Application Gateway**, which allows you to create custom error pages instead of displaying default error pages. You can use your own branding and layout using a custom error page. Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/custom-error) documentation for further reference.

Using ***Portal*** and ***PowerShell***, you can do configure the custom error page.

1. From Azure Portal > Application Gateways > Listeners > Navigate to particular listener where you want to specify an error page and specify the URL like below:

[image]

Using PowerShell for global custom error page:

```
$appgw   = Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name <app-gateway-name> -ResourceGroupName <resource-group-name>

$updatedgateway = Add-AzApplicationGatewayCustomError -ApplicationGateway $appgw -StatusCode HttpStatus502 -CustomErrorPageUrl "http://<website-url>"
```

Using PowerShell for a listener level error page:

```
$appgw   = Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name <app-gateway-name> -ResourceGroupName <resource-group-name>

$listener01 = Get-AzApplicationGatewayHttpListener -Name <listener-name> -ApplicationGateway $appgw

$updatedlistener = Add-AzApplicationGatewayHttpListenerCustomError -HttpListener $listener01 -StatusCode HttpStatus502 -CustomErrorPageUrl "http://<website-url>"
```

For more information, see [Add-AzApplicationGatewayCustomError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/add-azapplicationgatewaycustomerror) and [Add-AzApplicationGatewayHttpListenerCustomError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/add-azapplicationgatewayhttplistenercustomerror).